# SSRS how to deal with extra rows being created

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm extremely new to SQL Server Reporting services and I'm wondering how I'm able to remove repeating rows.

The table is grouped by the Goal Name and Goal Description.

I would like to remove the rows that are circled or not have the row repeat.

The inner join on the Funding table is pulling 3 records and it is creating 3 rows under Acad Priority 1 and Acad Priority 2. How can I configure the table so it only displays the first row under both the priority columns. Thank you in advance.

[image: SSRS Design View]

[image: Report View]

SQL statement:

```
SELECT         
    Plan_Master.Date_Submitted, Plan_Master.Filename, 
    Plan_Master.Department, Plan_Master.Last_Name, 
    Plan_Master.First_Name, Plan_Master.Email, 
    Plan_Master.Mission_Statement, 
    Plan_Master.Vision_Statement, Plan_Master.Goals_Objectives, 
    Initiative_Master.Name, Initiative_Master.Description, 
    Initiative_Master.Acad_Priority_1, Initiative_Master.Acad_Priority_2, 
    Initiative_Master.Acad_Priority_3, Initiative_Master.Acad_Priority_4, 
    Initiative_Master.Acad_Priority_5, Initiative_Master.Acad_Priority_6, 
    Initiative_Master.Operational_Sustainability, Initiative_Master.People_Plan, 
    Funding.Beginning_Fiscal_Year 
FROM            
    Plan_Master 
INNER JOIN
    Initiative_Master ON Plan_Master.Plan_ID = Initiative_Master.Plan_ID 
INNER JOIN
    Funding ON Initiative_Master.Initiative_ID = Funding.Initiative_ID
```

Comment: isNothing(Fields!GoalName.Value) = "True" ... pop this into Tablix->properties->Filters . In the filter expression pop the above and set it to type Boolean AND value = False. so where ever its null will hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to delete your detail row group (=), leaving the values under the group that's grouped by Goal Name, Goal Description, Acad Priority 1, and Acad Priority 2.  You should see it in the lower pane below the report design surface.

Comment: The first row of good data also seems to be in the DETAIL section. :\

Comment: It appears that the detail and parent group are on the same row, so deleting just the detail group (group only, without deleting rows/columns), should leave the good data fields under the parent group, and thus remove the blank duplicate records.

Comment: Thank you, I recreated the table and that part is fine now, but I'm still facing the issue where rows will be created with duplicate values to show a unique value from inner joining another table. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: I'm a little confused - you say the table part is fine now, does that mean you aren't seeing the repeating rows, or you still are?

Comment: This may a different question entirely, but I have one to many relationships and many results are being returned as a unique row. It looks like I'll need to do some reading regarding inner joins.